# why wont my recycler view scroll?

Tags: android, android-fragments, scroll, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

[image: screen]

been scowering the internet on this seems to happen a lot for a lot of reasons but I can't solve mine the two recycler views go into the view pagers but will not scroll, ive tried nested scroll views on the view pager and on the fragment holding the recycler view, tried just using the scroll behaviour tags on linear layouts, but no joy I tried changing the layout manager to horizontal and while it doesn't scroll it does give me the animation of a scroll view at the end of its layout, I'm using a grid layout, I've also heard it can come from using the app bar layout can someone offer some advice

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/wherethecardsgo">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
             />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_playlist_play_white_24dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/viewpager2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:background="@color/windowBackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tabs" />

</RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<include layout="@layout/content_main" />


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/plus" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and this is one of the recycler views

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".TwoFragment">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/card_grid"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Last of some portion of recyclerview doesn't scroll . is that is your problem?

Comment: yeah @Masum the recycler view doesnt scroll so the last portion of screen is lost theres 1 more row of cards under the row thats half visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

It was an issue of the appbar stealing focus so i pushed the appbar to the bottom of my layout and suddenly my recycler views are now scrolling! My xml now looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">



<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:id="@+id/wherethecardsgo">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
             />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_playlist_play_white_24dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/viewpager2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:background="@color/windowBackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tabs" />

</RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/plus" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this two properties in your recyclerView.

```
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:paddingBottom="60dp"
```

paddingBottom value you can change as your requirement

Comment: love your thinking but this didnt work, tried kicking it up slowly from 60 to 160 to 260 all the way up to 2660, but it just does not want to scroll

Answer (score 0):

Or use it Simple try this in your activity or fragment

```
recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            getView().getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true); // Pour Le Scroll pour qu'il soit opérationnel
            return false;
        }
    });
```